# Changing values in one column based on another in R

Tags: r

So I am using R and trying to change values in a data frame in one column by comparing two columns together.  I have something like

```
Median   MyPrice
10       0
20       18
20       20
30       35
15       NA
```

And I would like to say something like

```
if(MyPrice == 0 & MyPrice < Median){MyPrice <- 1
  }else if (MyPrice == Median){MyPrice <- 2
  }else if (MyPrice > Median){MyPrice <- 3
  }else {MyPrice <- 4}
```

To come up with

```
Median   MyPrice
10       1
20       1
20       2
30       3
15       4
```

But there is always an error.  I have also tried something like

```
for(i in MyPrice){if(MyPrice == 0 & MyPrice < Median){MyPrice <- 1
  }else if (MyPrice == Median){MyPrice <- 2
  }else if (MyPrice > Median){MyPrice <- 3
  }else {MyPrice <- 4}
  }
```

The for loop runs but it changes all values in MyPrice to 4.  I also tried the ifelse() function but it seemed to have an issue taking that many arguments at once.

I would also not be opposed to a new column being added to the end of the data frame if a solution like that is easier.

Comment: If your data structure is not a DataFrame this is normal

Comment: You can access specific elements in a data frame with the `[` operator. Try this: `my_data$MyPrice[my_data$MyPrice < my_data$Median & my_data$MyPrice == 0] <- 1`

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily have to use a `for` loop. Start by setting every comparison to 4.

```
> x$Comp=4
> x$Comp[x$Median>x$MyPrice]=1 #if Median is higher, comparison = 1
> x$Comp[x$Median==x$MyPrice]=2 #if Median is equal to MyPrice, comparison = 2
> x$Comp[x$Median<x$MyPrice]=3 #if Median is lower, comparison = 3
> x
  Median MyPrice Comp
1     10       0    1
2     20      18    1
3     20      20    2
4     30      35    3
5     15      NA    4
```

Answer (score 2):

Given your first argument that if `MyPrice == 0 & MyPrice < Median`, your 2nd row where Median: `20` and MyPrice: `18` should also be `4`. Here is a working nested ifelse statement with an NA handler after.

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(10,0,20,18,20,20,30,35,15,NA), byrow = T, ncol = 2))
colnames(df) <- c("Median","MyPrice")

df$NewPrice <- ifelse(df$MyPrice == 0 & df$MyPrice < df$Median, 1, 
                      ifelse(df$MyPrice == df$Median, 2, 
                             ifelse(df$MyPrice > df$Median, 3, 4)))
df$NewPrice[is.na(df$MyPrice)] <- 4
df
#  Median MyPrice NewPrice
#1     10       0        1
#2     20      18        4
#3     20      20        2
#4     30      35        3
#5     15      NA        4
```

Answer (score 0):

What about setting a new variable with all values in 4 and then, replace those cases where your conditions apply?
Simple, straight forward and easy to read :-)

```
#(Following the example from @Evans Friedland)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(10,0,20,18,20,20,30,35,15,NA), byrow = T, ncol = 2))
colnames(df) <- c("Median","MyPrice")

df <- mutate(df, myNewPrice = 4) #set my new price to 4, then edit by following your conditions
df$myNewPrice<- replace (df$myNewPrice, df$MyPrice == 0 & df$MyPrice < df$Median, 1)
df$myNewPrice<- replace (df$myNewPrice, df$MyPrice == df$Median                 , 2)
df$myNewPrice<- replace (df$myNewPrice, df$MyPrice > df$Median                  , 3)

df$myNewPrice <- as.numeric (df$myNewPrice) #might, might not be needed.
```